# How do I join different table columns into one column without concatenating contents in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

### Table_1

| policy_number_a | policy_number_b | policy_number_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pd0401 | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | pf0809 | tc2001 |
| NULL | NULL | tc3021 |

and so on.
I want the table to look like this

| policy_name | policy_number |
| --- | --- |
| a | pd0401 |
| b | pf0809 |
| c | tc3021 |

The output table can retail NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select COALESCE(policy_number_a, policy_number_b, policy_number_c) policy_number,  
case when policy_number_a IS NOT NULL THEN 'a' WHEN policy_number_b IS NOT NULL THEN 'b' ELSE 'c' END policy_name
from Table_1;
```

Comment: This is the best answer! Just what I was looking for. Thank you Amit!

Comment: if this was the best answer then why unaccepted after so many days ? Did you get better solution ? if yes, please share the solution.